# Google Maps API ImageMap Coordinate Limit

Tags: javascript, google-maps, coordinates

I have a Map (Google Maps API 3) that uses purely coordinates, as the world it shows is flat, there is no lat/lng. However, when I scroll down on the map, I reach the limit of what it shows before my images stop. Also the starting point of what it shows is far to the topleft, not centered at all.

I've seen the boundary and center commands, but they're for lat/lng and I have no idea how to make that work.

Here's my current .html:

http://pastebin.com/8KTu7Sii

It gets tiles from /tiles/, which has these contents:

http://pastebin.com/VHHn7rrZ

Unfortunately that folder is 1.7 GB, which would take me days to upload.

So the question is, how do I set the proper XY boundaries and how do I set a XY based Center?

Comment: Please clarify more your question. Did you want to plot multiple markers here? Also, if you got any error message, you can include that as well.

Comment: There is no error message. Apart from things like "screen_3_-1_0.png" not found, as those files don't exist.
gmaps tracks things in lng/lat, but I want to set world boundaries (not markers) and the starting center, in xy pixels.

So, lnglat gets a certain tile, which in my case is 1600px * 1600px. I want to set the center and world boundaries on a certain pixel.